# Setting up multisite with NginX

Tags: multisite

Does anyone have a tutorial/directions on how to set up multisite on NginX?  I'm using serverpilot with DigitalOcean...  I used all the standard reqs, looks like this post sor tof covers it: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-multisite-on-digitalocean-serverpilot

...but isn't quite a full answer or explanation.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should try out Easy Engine to set up Multisite on Nginx. https://rtcamp.com/easyengine/

Comment: Thanks.  I already used server pilot, can I add easy engine after?  I set up the multisite already, but it is not recognizing it because it is nginx instead of apache

Comment: AFAIK Easy Engine is an alternative to server pilot, with commands to install WordPress quickly. Anyways some of their articles should help you in setting. https://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/multisite/create-a-network/